# How to inflate different menu layouts for the same toolbar across fragments in an ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-actionbaractivity

I have an ActionBarActivity with 3 fragments and each has its own menu. The first two have a "next" menu item, and the last has a "save" menu item, so it works like a step by step. How can I inflate different menu layouts for each fragment? Remembering that I need to be able to navigate backwards and forwards and the toolbar has to be updated accordingly. Thanks in advance!